# Depth of field in macrophotography: stepping back + crop Vs reducing aperture?

Tags: macro, depth-of-field

There are multiple ways to increase depth of field (DoF) in macro photography. I know about focus stacking, but I have a question about which way is best for a single-shot. Two common options are:

1. Reduce aperture. The depth of field is essentially proportional to the F-number. This trades image quality for DoF because of diffraction.
2. Increase the distance to the subject, and then crop the image (i.e. zoom digitally to compensate the distance to subject). This also obviously trades image quality for DoF (less pixels, defects of the picture amplified by cropping if displayed/printed at the same size as the non-cropped image). This is more or less the same as taking the picture with a camera having a smaller sensor.

My question is: in which condition should I favor one or the other? In other words: at constant DoF, how does image quality vary if I change the distance to subject and aperture? Or, equivalently, at constant optical resolution (i.e. constant size of the airy disk relative to the size of the picture) changing distance and f-number, where will I get the maximal DoF?

Thanks,

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question with your note in #2?  I.e., given your desired resolution, back up until you have dropped to that with crop.  Beyond that you have to focus stack.  OTOH: If you're asking for a specific equation between aperture and "effective resolution" you should make that explicit, but I believe that question has already been dealt with here.

Comment: What are "_defects of the picture amplified by cropping_"? When you crop, you take some pixels away. There is no amplification.

Comment: @null: when you display (or print) the cropped picture, for a given display size, the more you crop, the more you need to rescale the picture, and the more you amplify the defects of the picture.

Comment: @feetwet: no, I haven't answered my own question. Sure, I can back up until I have something satisfactory (i.e. apply #2), but I can also reduce the F-number until I have something satisfactory (i.e. apply #1).

Comment: ok, you were implying a modified resolution due to scaling up the cropped image, got it

Comment: I still don't understand your last question: How do you define "best DoF"?  Do you mean *maximum* DoF?

Comment: Yes, maximum DoF. I changed it in the question.

Comment: @null, scaling up = interpolation != amplifying defects ?

Comment: @Olivier yeah, I couldn't really follow it either. I settled with the meaning of "the same sized print looks better if you have more pixels"

Comment: If your airy disk is 4 pixels (assuming your lens is diffraction-limited, which is the case in macro photography. If you are not diffraction-limited, replace "airy disk" with "image of a point"), and your image is 4000 pixels wide, you have an optical resolution of 1000. If you crop the image to only 1000 pixels, you have an optical resolution of 250. Your airy disk (or any defect of your lens that causes the image of a point to be bigger than a point) became bigger because you scaled it.

Comment: In complement to my previous comment: if you print your 4000 pixels image on a 10cm picture, your airy disk is 0.1mm wide on the printed image. If you crop your picture to 1000 pixels and print it with the same size, your airy disk is 0.4mm wide on the printout. Not surprising indeed: you're zooming-in (digitally), so small things become bigger.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy again, the problem you are describing arises from scaling up, not the cropping itself, cropping does not imply that any scaling happens.

Comment: At a given print/display size, cropping does imply scaling up. Repeating that it does not does not make your statement true. Sure, you can decide that you print/display cropped pictures smaller than the other (or use a smaller computer screen when you display cropped images), but what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

The pragmatic answer is: If possible, you make your aperture smaller to achieve the desired DOF. That way you do not trade in resolution.

Stepping back and cropping in is equivalent to choosing a longer focal length and stepping back (apart from the resulting resolution). It probably is an unpractical way to influence the DOF.

Mathematically, I think none of them is superior regarding the final DOF effect.

Comment: *make your aperture smaller [...]. That way you do not trade in resolution.*: Reducing aperture *does* reduce quality. As soon as you get close and have a non-flat subject, you need an aperture around f/16 in macro, and diffraction is dominant. Reducing the aperture increases diffraction (try taking a sharp shot at F/32 or more to see what I mean).

Comment: *Stepping back and cropping in is equivalent to choosing a longer focal length and stepping back*: not in macrophotography. The DoF is almost only a factor of the magnification ratio (read e.g. http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3064907237/depth-of-field-in-macro-photography). At magnification ratio 1:1, you'll get the same DoF with any focal length, even though the distance to subject will vary. OTOH, stepping back and cropping is exactly what you do if you decide your full-frame camera has a too shallow DoF, and use the same lens with an APS-C camera instead. It does increase DoF.

Comment: I still believe what actually influences the DOF is distance. It is similar to how I initially thought, focal lengths affected the compression of a scene (which they only indirectly do, since they force you to move to keep your composition). The distance to the subject is what determines the DOF in combination with the aperture.

Comment: You are not considering the fact that DoF decreases with long focal length. The distance increase is compensated by the focal increase. If you want more details, read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field (DOF formulae, Close-up).

Comment: I just do not find any statement that contradicts mine: Focal length indirectly affects DOF by generally forcing you to move.

Comment: "I just do not find any statement that contradicts mine": well, "for a given magnification, DOF is independent of focal length" does contradict your statement. "Stated otherwise, for the same subject magnification, at the same f-number, all focal lengths used on a given image format give approximately the same DOF" does too. And the formula given which is only a function of the magnification factor, the F-number, and circle of confusion too.

Comment: "Focal length indirectly affects DOF by generally forcing you to move.": no, focal length affects DoF directly for a given F-number. This is because at a given F-number, a larger focal length means a wider diaphragm (because F = diaphragm / focal length). And a wider diaphragm means catching light from a given point from more directions. Again, read the formula if you don't believe me. It does depend on *f*.

Comment: I have found a DOF simulator that proves me wrong. ;D

Comment: ;-). DoF stuff is a bit counter-intuitive. One reason you don't notice the DoF change when changing the focal length is: most zooms have smaller aperture at long focal length, hence turning the zoom ring increases the focal length while reducing the aperture, which keeps a more or less constant DoF.